# C++ Ranges Convert to std::string or search for ranges in ranges?

Tags: c++, find, range, std

I'm having a bit of a hard time to get hang of the concept of ranges. Basically I'm using [seqan3](https://docs.seqan.de/seqan/3-master-user/group__views.html) which comes with its own set of views. There I want to search for a subpattern in a text. Initially, I transform its own `Alphabet` representation into `char` using the following:

`auto seq = sequence | seqan3::views::to_char;`

As a quick and dirty solution, I thought using `std::string(seq)`. However, this seems to be deprecated. `std::string` is a container, so it should work with `ranges::to`? Wouldn't it be possible to do something like: `ranges::to<std::string>`? I mean I could do `ranges::to<std::vector<char>>` and then convert it to string, but that doesn't seem right. What is right way using ranges?

Alternatively, is there a way to search in `char` range for consecutive chars (e.g. substrings?). Searching for ranges in ranges?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `ranges::search`?